# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree while installing a pacakge in my expo account

Tags: react-native, expo

I have existing project, I update my SDK Version from 41 to 44 by following these steps.

1)Update to the latest version of Expo CLI: npm i -g expo-cli. expo-cli@5.4.3 or greater is required.
2)Run expo upgrade in your project directory.

After that I run expo start but got this error

**Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?**

Than I try to run npm install and getting this error

**ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree while installing a pacakge**

[enter image description here][1]

I am using Mac
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6hhN.png

Answer (score 0):

When you updated your SDK, it looks like npm could not resolve the dependency: `@react-native-community/masked-view`

You can try to run: `npm uninstall @react-native-community/masked-view` and then re-try `npm install`.

What may make things easier is to just give your dependency tree a good ol' refresh.

1. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json
2. re-run `npm install` in the ROOT of your project.

Triple check you are in the correct spot when running these commands.

Comment: Thanks @Corey for the answer, but while upgrading SDK there are many dependencies which didn't update so can not uninstall all of them.....

Comment: ** The following packages were not updated. You should check the READMEs for those repositories to determine what version is compatible with your new set of packages:
@react-native-community/masked-view, @react-native-community/picker, @react-native-community/toolbar-android, @react-navigation/bottom-tabs, @react-navigation/native, @react-navigation/stack, axios, md5, react-dark-mode-toggle, react-native-dropdown-picker, react-native-material-dropdown, react-native-paper, react-native-qrcode-svg, react-native-settings-list, react-native-swiper, react-native-vector-icons, react-player, **